# Mining Bitcoins on PC - Experiment, looking for advice or simple instructions

Tags: bitcoin-core, development

I am absolutely new to Bitcoin and mining, I know that mining at home using a PC is not worth even the time and takes years to get any income out of it. 
The thing is I need to mine at home using a PC for experimental purposes and education, so basically i just want to make something even like 0.0000001 bitcoin, and only bitcoin no other crypto currency.
I downloaded the Bitcoin Core wallet and downloaded all the years transactions to be up to date, where to go from there i have no idea, i found several miners but they are all confusing, I can't even find my address to start using the basic miners, so please could you give me a guide or a step by step instructions on how to proceed please? I need to do this alone not within a group (pool) of miners as most sites suggested.
Thank you

Comment: Solo mining, even with an asic, will essentially never return any money, since you either find a block or you get nothing. If you want to make even 1 satoshi, you would need to be in a pool, and this question is too broad for this site's format in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been commented, this is really not possible. You cannot solo mine Bitcoin with a PC. Even with an ASIC, you cannot solo mine. You simply won't have enough hash power to even get (as you said) 0.0000001 BTC.

If you are really set on mining, I would suggest you look at other currencies, and GPU based mining. You will however, be required to use mining pools. That is a necessity. If you are looking for a very simple GPU miner, you may checkout MinerGate (note: I am in no way affiliated with MinerGate, and I have never used their product).

Comment: As I mentioned in the post I have no intention of making any money, but I don't want to invest in hardware neither, the entire project is to show my students something in action and actually working, I guess it is not possible then, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

> **the entire project is to show my students something in action and actually working**

You can probably do this by effectively forking a cryptocurrency with a new isolated blockchain.

If Satoshi Nakamoto could get it all started with a few PCs in 2008, so can you.

However, you'd probably need to learn a substantial amount about your chosen cryptocurrency.